# Return a list of all tools a user needs for his hobbies

Tags: javascript, lodash

still new to lodash and I'm trying to return a list of all tools ('name's from data.tools) which a user needs for his activites.

the common data are "activites" and "tool" so I have to return for every tool the property "name" of it from usersTools.

```
var data = { 
   users: [
     { name: 'user1', email: 'user1@email.com', age: 'string', activites: [ 
   'photography', 'hiking', 'biking', 'sailing', 'relaxing' ] },

    { name: 'user2', email: 'user2@gmail.com', age: 15, activites: [ 'hiking', 'surviving', 'sewing', 'relaxing' ] },

    { name: 'user3', email: 'invalid mail', age: 10, activites: [ 'coding', 'hacking', 'relaxing' ] },

    { name: null, email: 'unregistered' }
  ],

  usersTools: [

    { name: 'hammer', tool: [ 'relaxing' ] },
    { name: 'camera', tool: [ 'photography' ] },
    { name: 'bike', tool: [ 'biking' ] },
    { name: 'keyboard', tool: [ 'hacking', 'coding' ] },
    { name: 'boat', tool: [ 'sailing' ] },
    { name: 'sail', tool: [ 'sailing' ] },
    { name: 'couch', tool: [ 'relaxing', 'hacking' ] },
    { name: 'tank', tool: [ 'nothing good' ] },
    { name: 'nuke', tool: [] },
    { name: 'backpack', tool: [ 'hiking' ] },
    { name: 'brain', tool: [ 'thinking' ] }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach`, `map` and `find` methods to get desired result.

```js
var data = {"users":[{"name":"user1","email":"user1@email.com","age":"string","hobbies":["photography","hiking","biking","sailing","relaxing"]},{"name":"user2","email":"user2@gmail.com","age":15,"hobbies":["hiking","surviving","sewing","relaxing"]},{"name":"user3","email":"invalid mail","age":10,"hobbies":["coding","hacking","relaxing"]},{"name":null,"email":"unregistered"}],"usersTools":[{"name":"hammer","tool":["relaxing"]},{"name":"camera","tool":["photography"]},{"name":"bike","tool":["biking"]},{"name":"keyboard","tool":["hacking","coding"]},{"name":"boat","tool":["sailing"]},{"name":"sail","tool":["sailing"]},{"name":"couch","tool":["relaxing","hacking"]},{"name":"tank","tool":["nothing good"]},{"name":"nuke","tool":[]},{"name":"backpack","tool":["hiking"]},{"name":"brain","tool":["thinking"]}]}

_.forEach(data.users, function(e, i) {
  e.hobbies = _.map(e.hobbies, function(a) {
    var name = _.find(data.usersTools, (t) => t.tool.includes(a));
    return name ? name.name : a
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you just want to return array of tool names for each user you can use `map` instead of `forEach` and return new array.

```js
var data = {"users":[{"name":"user1","email":"user1@email.com","age":"string","hobbies":["photography","hiking","biking","sailing","relaxing"]},{"name":"user2","email":"user2@gmail.com","age":15,"hobbies":["hiking","surviving","sewing","relaxing"]},{"name":"user3","email":"invalid mail","age":10,"hobbies":["coding","hacking","relaxing"]},{"name":null,"email":"unregistered"}],"usersTools":[{"name":"hammer","tool":["relaxing"]},{"name":"camera","tool":["photography"]},{"name":"bike","tool":["biking"]},{"name":"keyboard","tool":["hacking","coding"]},{"name":"boat","tool":["sailing"]},{"name":"sail","tool":["sailing"]},{"name":"couch","tool":["relaxing","hacking"]},{"name":"tank","tool":["nothing good"]},{"name":"nuke","tool":[]},{"name":"backpack","tool":["hiking"]},{"name":"brain","tool":["thinking"]}]}

var result = _.map(data.users, function(e, i) {
  return e.hobbies = _.map(e.hobbies, function(a) {
    var name = _.find(data.usersTools, (t) => t.tool.includes(a));
    return name ? name.name : a
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very effient nor optimal, using array.map and array.find:

```js
  var users = [
    { name: 'user1', hobbies: [ 'photography', 'hiking', 'biking', 'sailing', 'relaxing' ] },
    { name: 'user2', hobbies: [ 'hiking', 'surviving', 'sewing', 'relaxing' ] },
    { name: 'user3', hobbies: [ 'coding', 'hacking', 'relaxing' ] }
  ];

  var usersTools = [
    { name: 'hammer', tool: [ 'relaxing' ] },
    { name: 'camera', tool: [ 'photography' ] },
    { name: 'bike', tool: [ 'biking' ] },
    { name: 'keyboard', tool: [ 'hacking', 'coding' ] },
    { name: 'boat', tool: [ 'sailing' ] },
    { name: 'sail', tool: [ 'sailing' ] },
    { name: 'couch', tool: [ 'relaxing', 'hacking' ] },
    { name: 'tank', tool: [ 'nothing good' ] },
    { name: 'nuke', tool: [] },
    { name: 'backpack', tool: [ 'hiking' ] },
    { name: 'brain', tool: [ 'thinking' ] }
  ];

var user = users[0];
var tools = user.hobbies.map(hobby => usersTools.find(tool => tool.tool.indexOf(hobby) != -1) || null);
tools = tools.filter(tool => tool); // Remove null if any
tools = tools.map(tool => tool.name);
console.log(tools);
```